# Proposition A.4 in Hatcher (CW complexes are normal)

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Let us refer to the latest online version of Hatcher's Algebraic Topology, and the proof of Proposition A.4, as well as the inductive construction of an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of a subset of a CW complex, right above Proposition A.3.

Let $X$ be a CW complex, $x$ a point of $X$ and $U$ an open neighborhood of $X$ that contains $x$. The goal is to show that for small enough $\epsilon$ we can take $N_{\epsilon}(x)$ to be a subset of $U$. Hatcher says that we can do this inductively by requiring that for each $n$ the closure of $N_{\epsilon}^n(x)$ is inside $U$. Why do we need this condition, i.e., why not just take $\epsilon$ small enough such that simply $N_{\epsilon}^n(x)$ is inside $U$?

Comment: Can you write down the (proof of the) inductive step? At some point you have an $\epsilon$ such that $\overline{N^n_\epsilon(x)} \subseteq U$ and you need to construct an $\epsilon' < \epsilon$ such that $\overline{N^{n+1}_{\epsilon'}(x)} \subseteq U$. I'd guess that that argument does not allow you to prove the implication $N^n_\epsilon(x) \subseteq U \Rightarrow \exists \epsilon' < \epsilon. N^{n+1}_{\epsilon'}(x) \subseteq U$. Ultimately, that implication is still true, of course; it's just that the proof is easier with a stronger induction hypothesis.

Comment: @Magdiragdag: Interesting hint, thanks. Let me think about it.

Comment: Another way to this this is to use the Tietze Extension Theorem: a space $Y$ is normal if and only if every continuous function to the interval $[0,1]$ from a closed subspace of $Y$  extends over $Y$. So one proves that an adjunction space $B \cup_f X$, where $f: A \to B$ and $A$ is closed in $X$ is normal if and only if $X$ and $B$ are normal. (This is Exercise 6 on p. 131 of "Topology and Groupoids". )  This does the finite dimensional case and one then needs a limit argument.

Comment: @Magdiragdag: I feel i am almost there but can not write it down rigorously. Suppose $\bar{N_{\epsilon}^n(x)} \subset U$. By construction $N^{n+1}_{\epsilon}(x) = (1-\epsilon_{\alpha},1] \times \Phi_{\alpha}^{-1} \left(N_{\epsilon}^n(x) \right)$ for some $\epsilon_{\alpha}$. Now i am missing how to use  $\bar{N_{\epsilon}^n(x)} \subset U$ to prove  $\bar{N_{\epsilon}^{n+1}(x)} \subset U$ for sufficiently small $\epsilon_{\alpha}$ (even though i can visualize it a little bit).

Comment: My comment was slightly wrong in that the implication as stated goes only one way: if $B$ and $X$ are normal, then $B \cup_f X$ is normal. The proof via the stated theorem uses the pushout property for the adjunction space.

Comment: @RonnieBrown: Thanks. If we have only finitely many cells at each dimension (but possibly infinitely many dimensions) then we can get that $X$ is normal by induction on the skeleta, without any limit argument, right?

Comment: @Magdiragdag: And a little more progress: All we need to show is that for every $y \in \Phi^{-1}_{\alpha}(\overline{N_{\epsilon}^n(x)})$ there exists some $\epsilon_{\alpha,y}$ such that the radial line segment $[1-\epsilon_{\alpha,y},1] \times \left\{ y\right\}$ lies in $U$. Then, since $\Phi^{-1}_{\alpha}(\overline{N_{\epsilon}^n(x)})$ is compact, we can take the minimum such $\epsilon_{\alpha,y}$ as $\epsilon_{\alpha}$. Do you agree?

Comment: You can form $X^{n+1}$ from $X^n$ by attaching any number of $(n+1)$-cells. The final part of the argument uses $X$ is the union of the $X^n$ and a function is continuous on $X$  if and only if it is continuous on each $X^n$. These arguments reflect the idea that the chief aim of the CW-topology on $X$ is to be able to construct continuous functions on $X$.